# What is a fat point?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

In our scriptum we're talking about singularities. And there is the term "fat point" (for example of "tangent of fat point") . I cannot find any definition :-/ Has somebody an idea?

Comment: Usually means a point scheme with non-reduced structure sheaf.

Comment: What is a "scriptum"?

Answer (score 8):

The fat point supported at $Z$ with multiplicity $k$ is the non-reduced scheme defined by $I(Z)^k$. This is often denoted $kZ$ in the fat points literature; it must not be confused with a zero-cycle. Slightly more generally, the fat point scheme supported at distinct points $Z_1,\dotsc,Z_t$ with multiplicities $k_1,\dotsc,k_t$ is the union of the fat points, that is the scheme defined by $\bigcap I(Z_i)^{k_i}$. This is often denoted $k_1 Z_1 + \dotsb + k_t Z_t$.

For a fat point scheme in affine or projective $n$-dimensional space, $\deg(kZ) = \binom{k+n-1}{n}$ and $\deg(k_1 Z_1 + \dotsb + k_t Z_t) = \sum \binom{k_i + n-1}{n}$ (*not* degree $k$ or $k_1+\dotsb+k_t$).

Comment: This only makes sense if $Z$ is a (reduced) closed point embedded in some ambient scheme. Moreover, it is by no means true that every fat point is of this form!

Comment: Well, people use terminology to mean whatever they want it to mean. The people who actually study fat points use the definition that I've given (where, yes, $Z$ is a reduced point).

Comment: And yes, embedded, as you say.

Comment: Ok, but my other comment still stands: a point in $\mathbb A^n$ can have many other scheme structures than the ones you list, and I personally think those equally well deserve to be called 'fat/thick points'.

Comment: Although a review of the literature does seem to suggest that some modern texts reserve 'fat point' to mean specifically the $n$-th infinitesimal neighbourhood of a point embedded into a smooth $k$-variety, as opposed to more general 'thick points' that are arbitrary Artinian schemes.

Comment: I have been confused about this in talks, it does seem like there are distinct schools of people around, one apparently involving RvDdB, myself and no doubt others, for whom "fat point" would just mean an embedded zero-dimensional subscheme of some ambient space whose reduced underlying subscheme is a single point, and then this much more specific definition proposed by ZT.

Comment: @Balazs To be clear, it's not my definition to propose. What I described is a common definition in a certain part of the algebraic geometry literature. But it seems that others use the term differently. It seems advisable for authors and speakers to give clear definitions: "Let $Z$ be a fat point, which for this talk means..."

Answer (score 1):

The definition I know is definition 1A.2 in ["Lecture Notes on Motivic Cohomology"](https://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim02.pdf) by Mazza, Voevodsky, Weibel.

Comment: Warning: this is a completely unusual definition. The standard one is the one discussed in the comments..

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273049/what-is-a-fat-point#comment1177037_454696), @‍Mohan's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273049/what-is-a-fat-point#comment675806_273049) and @‍ZachTeitler's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/273056) giving the standard definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I will try my best to see that these definitions are equivalent.